# XAMPP Warning Notice: Undefined offset; Aim to keep warnings on but allowing code to run

Tags: php

I have the following:

```
$results = array();
$results[0] = $results[0] + $value;
```

which causes the warning in XAMPP

> Warning  Notice: Undefined offset;

because $results[0] does not have an intial value. Hosting the site assumes the value 0 on the first pass but locally XAMPP throws the warning.

I can bypass this by establishing the value of $results[0] using:

```
$results = array();
$results[0] = 0;
$results[0] = $results[0] + $value;
```

But if there is an indefinate number of keys (perhaps a $loop from 0 to n) can I establish the array with 0 values by default, without explicitly specifying 0 for each key, so that the following:

```
$results = array();
$results[$loop] = $results[$loop] + $value[$loop];
```

will work for any value of $loop with warning in XMAPP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to resolve this issue it to use **isset()** function. It will allow you to check the existing of an element in the array thus avoiding the error message.

Example

```
$results = array();
if((isset($results[$loop])) && (isset($value[$loop]))){
    $results[$loop] = $results[$loop] + $value[$loop];
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks - I thought this might be the way but given this is just one of lots of arrays I was hoping to avoid lots of ifs. Thank you.

Comment: You can use short notation in place of "if". ```$results[$loop] =( (isset($results[$loop]) ? $results[$loop] : 0)  + (isset($value[$loop])) ? $value[$loop] : 0;```